Prevent bluetooth earbuds/headphones from auto-connecting to MacOS Sonoma
I have combed the internet, chatgpt, brave's leo, AskDifferent... to no avail. I am unable to find a solution for this.
I've tried creating an Automator app to run on startup, but it won't work with a long-wait command like blueutil --wait-connect ID, so I tried to create launchd agent, which also doesn't work as intended.
I cannot believe that in 2024 there's no solution to avoid Audio devices from connecting automatically to MacOS.
This solution doesn't work:
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist DontPageAudioDevices 1

Adding devices to an ignore list in that .plist file doesn't work either, as (I suspect) this Ignore-Devices array is not used by bluetoothd anymore.
Toothfairy app doesn't achieve this either.
I don't want to turn Bluetooth off completely, I just want to be able to decide, when and what I connect to the computer or if I prefer this to happen automatically.
Thanks in advance.

This can help: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/stop-bluetooth-from-autoconnecting-to-my-headphones.2331131/

It unfortunately doesn't. I have already scouted the internet as I mentioned. That guy created a script running continuosly and disconnecting a certain device, but then you need to manually stop the script to be able to actually connect manually. It's not that I don't want the buds to connect at all, I simply want to decide when to connect.
